# Pass a cookie back to a user before proxy_pass

Tags: nginx

I've been setting up an nginx reverse proxy to handle requests based on logging in against a LDAP database. The basic guide is here https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-ldap-auth . The problem I have is that I want to set an expiry time on the cookie (easy to do), and that every time any resource is accessed, the expiry time gets bumped ten minutes into the future.  I don't have access to the code beyond the proxy, so I can't get that to update the cookie, but I do have some python code which receives the auth_request. What I would ideally like is for the cookie to be returned to the user, and then redirected to the proxy_pass.

Here is a fragment of my nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
         auth_request /auth_proxy; #the python authentication routine checks the cookie at this address.
         error_page 401 403 =200 /login #Python login page
         proxy_pass http://ADifferentServerWhenLoggedIn.org.
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is following the example provided in the docs for [`auth_request`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html#auth_request) and provide a location corresponding to the authentication path.

You could then use [`add_header`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header) to insert HTTP headers such as `Set-Cookie`.